# Core data display fetched data issue

Tags: swift, core-data

i'm facing a weird situation. I'm trying to print my fetched data from core data, but that's waht i'm getting as result: NSAsynchronousFetchResult.

This my entity class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Contact)
class Contact: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var group: String

}
```

and this is my class to fetch the results:

```
func fetchCategories() {
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var error: NSError?

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contact")
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
            fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        let fetchedResults = context.executeRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)

        if let results = fetchedResults {

            var fetchedData = [results]

            for contents in fetchedData {
                println(contents.name)
            }
        } else {
            println("\(error)")
        }
    }
```

any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result to your custom type.

```
if let results = fetchedResults as? [Contact]
```

And this does not seem right, you are wrapping results into another array:

```
var fetchedData = [results]
```

Just loop through results.